# How can i get specific data from a specific date from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table in PostgreSQL like below...

| emp_id | emp_name | date | shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Rana | 01.07.2019 | G |
| 001 | Rana | 02.07.2019 | G |
| 001 | Rana | 03.07.2019 | G |
| 001 | Rana | 04.07.2019 | G |
| 001 | Rana | 05.07.2019 | Off |
| 001 | Rana | 06.07.2019 | G |
| 001 | Rana | 07.07.2019 | G |
| 001 | Rana | 30.06.2020 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 01.07.2019 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 02.07.2019 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 03.07.2019 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 04.07.2019 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 05.07.2019 | Off |
| 002 | Tame | 06.07.2019 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 07.07.2019 | G |
| 002 | Tame | 30.06.2020 | G |

I would like to pass "date=04.07.2019" into the parameter, then print will ...

| emp_id | emp_name | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Rana | G | Off | G | G | G | G | G |
| 002 | Tame | G | Off | G | G | G | G | G |

I would also like to pass another "date=26.11.2019" into the parameter, then print will ...

| emp_id | emp_name | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday | Monday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Rana | G | G | G | Off | G | G | G |
| 002 | Tame | G | G | G | Off | G | G | G |

Comment: Why is it that you want data for all weekdays, when you pass specific date? How does `04.07.2019` expand into `thu, fri, sat, sun, mon, tue, wed`?

Comment: #Rohit Jain: Actually i want to know weekly shift status, sometime employee change their shift, so it is need to know total weekdays from a specific date. It is possible to control row limit by "LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0", but those day's need week value in column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE Expression` and `Aggregate` function

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e1ac66d4dda4b505807da440b2eb6ba1)**

```
SELECT E.emp_name,E.emp_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Monday' THEN E.shift Else NULL END) AS "Monday",
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN E.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Tuesday",
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Wednesday' THEN E.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Wednesday",
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Thursday' THEN E.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Thursday",
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Friday' THEN E.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Friday",
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Saturday' THEN E.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Saturday",
       MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Sunday' THEN E.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Sunday"
FROM
(
  SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date 
  FROM generate_series('04.07.2019'::timestamp,'04.07.2019'::timestamp + INTERVAL '6 day','1 day'::interval) dd
) D JOIN Employee E ON E.date = D.date_trunc
GROUP BY  E.emp_name,E.emp_id;
```

**Updated Query**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9c50bb5081c06165da34664cc81e6f1a)**

As per [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) suggestion, below is the modified query, which will be more easier to read by using [`filter()`](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter).

```
SELECT E.emp_name,E.emp_id,
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Monday') AS "Monday",
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Tuesday') AS "Tuesday",
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Wednesday') AS "Wednesday",
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Thursday') AS "Thursday",
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Friday') AS "Friday",
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Saturday') AS "Saturday",
       MAX(e.shift) filter (where trim(to_char(D.date_trunc, 'Day')) = 'Sunday') AS "Sunday"
FROM (
  SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date 
  FROM generate_series('04.07.2019'::timestamp,'04.07.2019'::timestamp + INTERVAL '6 day','1 day'::interval) dd
) D JOIN Employee E ON E.date = D.date_trunc
GROUP BY  E.emp_name,E.emp_id;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: In Postgres this can be written with a `filter()` condition that is a lot easier to read. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9c50bb5081c06165da34664cc81e6f1a

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank for the suggestion, I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using PostgreSQL 9.2, so filter() condition doesn't work.

Comment: @ZakirHossain Then why dont you try first query?

Comment: @VigneshKumarA here is an another function that each employee has 365 records, that's mean 1 year record.

Comment: @ZakirHossain so what your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Below query also work...

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f006c352a47efd59f20083ff029712d6)**

```
select  e.emp_id,e.emp_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Saturday' THEN e.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Saturday",
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Sunday' THEN e.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Sunday",
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Monday' THEN e.shift Else NULL END) AS "Monday",
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN e.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Tuesday",
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Wednesday' THEN e.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Wednesday",
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Thursday' THEN e.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Thursday",
    MAX(CASE WHEN trim(to_char(e.date, 'Day')) = 'Friday' THEN e.shift Else NULL EnD) AS "Friday"
from    employee e
group by e.emp_id,e.emp_name
order by e.emp_id
```